# How to read data from xlsx in Perl if the xlsx file have collapsed rows

Tags: excel, perl, xlsx

Is the perl library `Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX` able to parse xlsx files that has collapsed rows?

I am trying to parse a xlsx file generated from another program. The xlsx file might have collapsed rows.

Trying to understand is there any methods in this library that can be used to expand all collapsed rows while parsing the file?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will count the collapsed columns.